# Spring taskexecutor probleme double execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring taskExecutor on my project how send mail every 15min, all work right but when its time to execute the task, it execute 2 times!! I dont know why or where is the problem: 
there is part of my mvc-dispatcher.xml:

```
<task:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="AlertNewTickets" class="com.gepmag.service.AlertNewTickets"></bean>
```

and here the à part of the task:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 900000) //
      //@Scheduled(cron="*/9000 * * * * ?")
          public void checking() throws MessagingException
            {

    System.out.println("check AlertResponse: "+new Date());
}
```

Comment: I recommed you to add DEBUG logging with `thread indicator` for your `@Scheduled` method and take a look which threads invoke your methods. Assume you configure scheduling twice: from annotation and from xml

Comment: Can you show your Spring configuration? Are you also using `applicationContext.xml` not just 'mvc-dispatcher.xml'?

Comment: If it executes twice you either have loaded the configuration twice (i.e once by the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`) or you have also a `@Component` (or the likes of it) annotation on the `AlertNewTickets` together with component-scanning resulting in 2 instances. Either way there are multiple instances of your bean else it wouldn't execute twice.